# Should a symbol with a plural name be considered plural?

Tags: computing

Sometimes symbols like variables take a plural name (fx when referring to a container), for example:

```
languages = ['English', 'French', 'German']
```

When then referring to the variable in for example documentation, should it be considered singular or plural (eg should one use singular or plural form of verbs). That is should I write:

`languages` contains the supported languages.

or

`languages` contain the supported languages.

Also note that it's a possibility that the container only contains one element.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be more about software naming conventions than English language. As you describe it, “Languages” appears to be the name of a set that may contain none, one or many languages. The set should be treated as a singular term.

Comment: The question is not about whether to call it `language` or `languages`, it's already decided to call it `languages`. The question is whether the symbol then should be considered a plural or singular noun, ie whether I should write "`languages` contain..." or "`languages` contains...".

Comment: And Anton has answered that. `languages` is a single set, so it takes a singular verb (just as I did with *is*).